# git clone without asking for users password

Tags: git, bash, ssh, git-bash, sshd

I want to create public git repository on my dedicated server for anyone to clone but it keeps asking me for password for git user.

I have created user named git without password. Used:

> passwd -d git

Unfortunately every time I try to do:

> git clone git@myhost:myrepo.git

I'm getting asked for password.

I have tried setting in `sshd_config`

```
Match user git 
        PermitEmptyPasswords yes 
        PasswordAuthentication yes
```

With either yes and no for `PasswordAuthentication` but still no use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems doing it over ssh is impossible. It will always ask for password unless you copy your public key.

The solution is to use `git daemon` and clone repository over git:// protocol

`git clone git://hostname/directory`

For more information about it I suggest `git help daemon`

Tip:
Remember you need to give it read privileges. From my experience setting others: `chmod -R o+r project.git` won't work for some reason. You have to permit git access via either author or group. You can disallow write access to your repo on daemon level ( default behaviour ).

Comment: should be
git@github.com:<account>/<project>.git

Answer (score 0):

Same procedure as setup passwordless ssh login.

1. generate a passphase less private/public key pair

   ```
   ssh-keygen <your-key-filename>
   ```
2. ssh-copy-id to your host server
3. add a config file under your client .ssh folder (note: this step is optional), the contents of the config file similar to the following:

   ```
   Host <git-server>
           Hostname <ip-of-your-git-server>
           User <your-git-user-name>
           Port <your-git-server-port>
           IdentityFile <path-to-your-private-key>
   ```
4. try to login your host through ssh:

   ```
   ssh <git-server>
   ```
5. now you can clone, push, pull, whatever to your git-server

Edit: try to google "password less ssh login" for more detail and tricks.

Comment: It is suppose to be a ```public``` git repository so any rsa id copying is out of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. BTW, I think this can't be done with git protocol, and the only option left is setup a web based frontend for public http/https access.

Comment: Than how does github does it?

Comment: Git using RSA key for git protocol, and HTTPS for public access.