# Git asks for username/password

Tags: github, repo

I downloaded files from original git repo, modified them and uploaded them to my own repo. Now, when I clone original repo, it does not ask for username and password, but when I clone my repo it asks. But I dont want to ask, how can it be fixed?

Actual repositories:

- Original repo: https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-inference
- My repo: https://github.com/eligosoftware/jetson_inference

P.S.: My own repo is public as well as the original one.

Comment: Is your personnal repo private?

Comment: no, it is public.

Comment: We can't tell for sure without knowing more details, but in the meantime go ahead and Google for "don't ask for password when cloning a Git repository" and see if any of the dozens of articles that show up help. Here's one right here on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099843/git-clone-without-asking-for-users-password

Comment: Is [this](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password) helping you?

Comment: I just changed 2 text files from the original repo and pushed all files to my own repo. that is it. I fear that when I pushed to my repo, it took credentials from my pc.

Comment: `no, it is public` <= well git is actually behaving as if it is not. Since all of this is supposed to be public, uris to the actual repos would help to rule this out. Add them as an edit to your question.

Comment: both repos use https

Comment: Original repo: https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-inference
My repo https://github.com/eligosoftware/jetson_inference

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/af3869e7febab74224bac1ad125d2732)

Comment: After clearing global credentials and restarting it doesn't ask for username and password.

Comment: The original repository *is* public and yours *is not* public. (Create a private-browsing window in whatever browser you like that has private browsing, and try to access your own repository on GitHub, and you'll get a 403 error because it's only available to *you*.)

Answer (score -2):

After clearing global credentials and restarting it doesn't ask for username and password.

Comment: This behavior sounds system-dependent. But you have not told us what system you are running. So this Q and A is unlikely to be helpful as it stands. Moreover, there is no programming here; the entire discussion sounds like a better candidate for SuperUser or similar.

Comment: the system I use was Jetson Nano on ubuntu based OS